# Spring MVC Allow header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I assume that Spring Dispatcher automatically include Allow header when a particular URL is requested via OPTIONS method. Is there any way we can override the Allow header which Spring sets Out of box? If yes, what would be the best way?

Comment: What is "Spring Dispatcher" and what version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I meant to say Dispatcher servlet.

FYI. Answer to this question is HttpServlet's doOptions method identifies the methods supported by DispatcherServlet and sets the OPTIONS header. So what we can do is to add a filter to explicitly override the OPTIONS header